# Посчитать несколько значений при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android

[image: Как это выглядит]

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    double hw1 = Double.parseDouble(hwPr.getText().toString());
    double hw2 = Double.parseDouble(hw.getText().toString());
    double resultHW = (hw2 - hw1) * HW_KEF;
    /*BigDecimal hw = new BigDecimal(resultHW);
    hw = hw.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    textResultHW.setText("" + hw);*/
    textResultHW.setText("" + resultHW);

    double cw1 = Double.parseDouble(cwPr.getText().toString());
    double cw2 = Double.parseDouble(cw.getText().toString());
    double resultCW = (cw2 - cw1) * CW_KEF;
    /*BigDecimal cw = new BigDecimal(resultCW);
    cw = cw.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    textResultCW.setText("" + cw);*/
    textResultCW.setText("" + resultCW);

    double elPr1 = Double.parseDouble(t1Pr.getText().toString());
    double el1 = Double.parseDouble(t1.getText().toString());
    double resultT1 = (el1 - elPr1) * T1_KEF;
    /*BigDecimal elT1 = new BigDecimal(resultT1);
    elT1 = elT1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    textResultT1.setText("" + elT1);*/
    textResultT1.setText("" + resultT1);

    double elPr2 = Double.parseDouble(t2Pr.getText().toString());
    double el2 = Double.parseDouble(t2.getText().toString());
    double resultT2 = (el2 - elPr2) * T2_KEF;
   /* BigDecimal elT2 = new BigDecimal(resultT2);
    elT2 = elT2.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    textResultT2.setText("" + elT2);*/
    textResultT2.setText("" + resultT2);

    double elPr3 = Double.parseDouble(t3Pr.getText().toString());
    double el3 = Double.parseDouble(t3.getText().toString());
    double resultT3 = (el3 - elPr3) * T3_KEF;
    /*BigDecimal elT3 = new BigDecimal(resultT3);
    elT3 = elT3.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    textResultT3.setText("" + elT3);*/
    textResultT3.setText("" + resultT3);
}
}
```

Что здесь не так? При попытке рассчитать, приложение закрывается. Хотя когда оставляешь только первый расчет:

```
`double hw1 = Double.parseDouble(hwPr.getText().toString());
 double hw2 = Double.parseDouble(hw.getText().toString());
 double resultHW = (hw2 - hw1) * HW_KEF;
 /*BigDecimal hw = new BigDecimal(resultHW);
 hw = hw.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
 textResultHW.setText("" + hw);*/
 textResultHW.setText("" + resultHW);`
```

в отведенный для результата TextView все правильно считает..

Comment: а Вы не могли бы чуть подробнее описать задачу и чуть подробнее описать что Вы получаете в итоге?

Comment: есть несколько полей для ввода данных (EditText), пользователь их все должен заполнить.  Потом при нажатии Button, все эти значения должны посчитаться и вывестись в отведенное для них TextView

Comment: опишите это в задаче (не все читают комментарии). И опишите что происходит по факту

Comment: если у вас аварийно завершается программа, добавьте в вопрос стектрейс при аварийной остановке.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас ошибка в том, что не проверяете - введены ли данные, прежде чем переводить их double.